# Ubuntu for Windows when running script gives mv: cannot stat error

Tags: bash, scripts, nodejs, ubuntu-forums

I have a node project that uses child_process to kick off a script. The script loops over files, converts them to image, stores the path to each in an array and returns the array to node. then I convert to string in order to read it and do a console.log to see the results. I am getting an error however:

```
I/O Error: Couldn't open file `'/mnt/c/localBarcodereader/pdf/calBarcodereader/pdf/K0XY92E6@DWEMIT6.glagsec107.SEC1.pdf': No such file or directory.
mv: cannot stat '/mnt/c/localBarcodereader/pdf/calBarcodereader/pdf/K0XY92E6@DWEMIT6.glagsec107.SEC1.pdf': No such file or directory`
```

I do not see this error when running in a linux server. Only when I run this in Ubuntu for Windows.
I noticed in the error that the directory path is being copied:
calBarcodereader/pdf

here is my script:

`#! /bin/bash

    ndate=`date +%F_%T
    `OIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; array=($(find /mnt/c/localBarcodereader/pdf -type f - 
    size +0b)); IFS=$OIFS
    for item in "${array[@]}"
    do`

```
file=$item
file="${file:9}"
fname="${file::-4}"
PATHTOIMG= "/mnt/c/localBarcodereader/pdfimage/${fname}_${ndate}"
if [ ${file: -4} == ".pdf" ]; then
# pdftoppm /mnt/c/localBarcodereader/pdf/K0WNZLLW@ERNWZOO.glagsec101.SEC1.pdf /mnt/c/localBarcodereader/pdfimage/test -png -f 1 -singlefile -rx 1500 -ry 1500
    pdftoppm /mnt/c/localBarcodereader/pdf/$file $PATHTOIMG -png -f 1 -singlefile -rx 1500 -ry 1500
    mv /mnt/c/localBarcodereader/pdf/$file /mnt/c/localBarcodereader/pdfarchive
    echo $PATHTOIMG
else
        mv /mnt/c/localBarcodereader/pdf/$file /mnt/c/localBarcodereader/pdfarchive
fi done
```

and my node code:

```
const cp = require('child_process')

try {
const data = cp.execSync('/mnt/c/localBarcodereader/barcodeScript.sh');
if (data.toString() !== "") {
    console.log(data.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

When the script was running on the Linux server the path name appears to have been much shorter.

As a quick fix change this line:

```bash
file="${file:9}"
```

to this:

```bash
file="${file:30}"
```

Essentially you were changing the variable `file` from:

```bash
/mnt/c/localBarcodereader/pdf/K0XY92E6@DWEMIT6.glagsec107.SEC1.pdf
```

to:

```bash
calBarcodereader/pdf/K0XY92E6@DWEMIT6.glagsec107.SEC1.pdf
```

When the intention was to change `file` to be:

```bash
K0XY92E6@DWEMIT6.glagsec107.SEC1.pdf
```

There are better ways of doing this and I'll try to revise the answer (and reformat your question) a bit later.